# Composer unable to resolve requirements

Tags: composer-php

When you look at [log](https://travis-ci.org/meridius/helpers/jobs/123974858#L167), you can see this, which doesn't make any sense:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
packages.

  Problem 1
    - meridius/coding-standard 1.0.0 requires consistence/coding-standard ^0.10.1 -> satisfiable by consistence/coding-standard[0.10.1].
    - meridius/coding-standard 1.0.1 requires consistence/coding-standard ^0.10.1 -> satisfiable by consistence/coding-standard[0.10.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install consistence/coding-standard 0.10.1
    - Installation request for meridius/coding-standard * -> satisfiable by meridius/coding-standard[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
```

The project I am trying to build has `"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5"` and `"meridius/coding-standard": "^1"` as requirements. The update passes fine in these cases:

- if I remove either of mentioned requirements, clear vendor and update
- if I remove either of mentioned requirements, clear vendor, update **and** add the removed requirement back again and do update

I don't understand why the second case works but when both packages are required it does not.

The culprit seems to be `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` which is required by `consistence/coding-standard` and straight in the project I am building.

If I do `composer show -t | grep -C4 squizlabs/php_codesniffer` I can see that `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` is required several times but all the version constraints seem fine to me.

You can see the [composer.json here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meridius/helpers/93beda1c65291476f5053df71f0cb63d1119774b/composer.json).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in Composer.

This works:

```
"require-dev": {
    "meridius/coding-standard": "*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5"
},
```

This doesn't work:

```
"require-dev": {
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5",
    "meridius/coding-standard": "*"
},
```

As far as I know Composer the order of requirements should not matter (someone might confirm this). [Report it as a bug](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues).

Comment: Thank you for that pointer. It has now reported [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5250), should you be interested.